# Change entry in Python Pandas dataframe if other entries in rows match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called All_samp where I want to change entries in a column to the lowest value if other entries in that same row match entries in a different row. For example, I have this dataframe

| index | chromosome | start | sample | no_calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | chr1 | 190098060 | 8.1 | 600 |
| 23 | chr1 | 190098060 | 9.1 | 858 |
| 24 | chr1 | 190098078 | 8.1 | 201 |
| 25 | chr1 | 190098093 | 8.1 | 250 |
| 26 | chr1 | 190098093 | 8.1 | 32 |
| 27 | chr1 | 190098093 | 8.1 | 271 |
| 28 | chr1 | 190098119 | 8.1 | 288 |
| 29 | chr1 | 190098123 | 10.1 | 146 |
| 30 | chr1 | 190098123 | 10.1 | 307 |
| 31 | chr10 | 190098123 | 8.1 | 366 |
| 32 | chr1 | 190098160 | 8.1 | 298 |

If chromosome, start, and sample match are the same, then I want no_calls to be the minimum value of the matching rows. Therefore, this is the result I am looking for:

| index | chromosome | start | sample | no_calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | chr1 | 190098060 | 8.1 | 600 |
| 23 | chr1 | 190098060 | 9.1 | 858 |
| 24 | chr1 | 190098078 | 8.1 | 201 |
| 25 | chr1 | 190098093 | 8.1 | 32 |
| 26 | chr1 | 190098093 | 8.1 | 32 |
| 27 | chr1 | 190098093 | 8.1 | 32 |
| 28 | chr1 | 190098119 | 8.1 | 288 |
| 29 | chr1 | 190098123 | 10.1 | 146 |
| 30 | chr1 | 190098123 | 10.1 | 146 |
| 31 | chr10 | 190098123 | 10.1 | 366 |
| 32 | chr1 | 190098160 | 8.1 | 298 |

I tried to do this was by making a series of the no_calls column using itertuples and a nested loop to make the changes to the entries. With this, I should be able to replace the no_calls column with the amended series. This is what my code looked like

```
no_calls = []
for row1 in All_samp.itertuples():
    for row2 in All_samp.itertuples(): 
        if row1[0] != row2[0] and (row1[1] == row2[1] and row1[2] == row2[2] and row1[3] == row2[3]):
            print(row1[0], row2[0], row1[4], row2[4], min(row1[4], row2[4]))
            no_calls.append(min(row1[4], row2[4]))
            break
        else:
            no_calls.append(row1[4])
            break
```

The result is simply giving me a list of the original no_calls entries, and I imagine it's because my 'if' statement is only going through the first iteration instead of cycling through all rows. Once I get the loop to work, I will replace the column with the list with

```
All_samp['no_calls'] = no_calls
```

If there are any ideas how to help me fix my loop or even a completely different way to get the minimum no_calls values in my dataframe (I am certain there is something better than the loops, I would greatly appreciate it.

Also, if there is a way that I can present the dataframes other than as a table on StackOverflow such that it's easier to work with them directly, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Groupby` and `transform('min')`

```
df['NO_CALLS']=df.groupby(['CHROMOSOME','START','SAMPLE'])['NO_CALLS'].transform('min')
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch... Are there certain functions that can go into transform?

Comment: almost all functions I think, max, nunique, sum etc